# Load an ActiveRecord models from a YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, yaml

I'd like to create an ActiveRecord readonly model that is populated from a **YAML** file.
Here is my model:

```
class Building  < ActiveRecord::Base

?right_callback_to_use? :load_data_from_yaml
after_initialize :readonly!

def load_data_from_yaml
    #implementation?
end

end
```

And here is my yml

```
- id: 1
  name: Building 1
- id: 2
  name: Building 2
```

How can I load data from my external yml file and associate them with my model?

And how should I call my function `load_data_from_yaml` only once and only at the very beginning of my application?

I'm using **Rails 4**.

Thank you!

Comment: depends on how the structure of the YAML file, you can do `self.class.create(Yaml.load_file("file.yaml"))` where `file.yaml` is the name of you YAML file

Comment: @bjhaid I added the basic structure of my YAML file ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `YAML` structure you added to your question the below should work, assuming `file.yml` is the name of you `YAML` file

```
require 'yaml' #I think rails does this already for you so it might not be necessary

def load_data_from_yaml
  YAML.load_file("file.yml").each { |building| self.class.create!(building) }
end
```

if the size of your `YAML` file is huge and you want some speed you could have a look at: https://github.com/bjhaid/active_record_bulk_insert

and you method would look like this:

```
def load_data_from_yaml
  self.class.bulk_insert(YAML.load_file("file.yml"))
end
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful. I have also another problem: I can't find the right callback for my model: I'd like to load data at the really beginning and only once and so call `Building.all` without any kind of initialization. It is possible?

Comment: you can put all that in `db/seed.rb` and then run `rake db:seed` before running your application, and you have the DB loaded

Answer (score 3):

I think you're searching for [ActiveHash](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash). This library acts as read-only ActiveRecord and lets you define the data as hash, YAML or JSON. It even supports relations!